# Read .txt file in array and check if variable input exist in array

Tags: php, jquery

This is my HTML code:

```
<?php
        $filename = 'codes.txt';
        $data = file($filename);
         foreach($data as $key => $val){
             $array[] =  $val;
         }
?>
<form id="checkinput" action="#">
<input class="zipcodes" name="zipcodes" value="" type="text">
<input class="zip-sub" type="button" value="Continue" id="submit">
</form>
```

Thi is jQuery code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.zip-sub').click(function() {
        var zip = jQuery('.zipcodes').val();
        var zipcodelist = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
        if( jQuery.inArray(zip, zipcodelist) != -1){
             alert('value is .txt file !');
        } else {
             alert('value is not .txt file');
        }
    });

});
```

This is type of some variable in .txt file:

```
12345
23456
56789
```

***What i need: when i fill data in input field i can check its in variable in .txt file or not***

Its working with last variable in array, not at all. I dont know where's the code is wrong ? Pls help. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm not clear on what's supposed to happen here?

Comment: just edited what i need. Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain what this means: "Its working with last variable in array, not at all."

Comment: are you sure that `zip` and `zipcodelist` are returning the right variables in the right format? Can you try `console.log(zip)` and `console.log(zipcodelist )` to confirm?

Comment: Its working good if i fill "56789" in input field (it will be showing msg "value is .txt file !"  as message in jQuery code) but it didnt working with "12345" and "23456"..

Comment: when you say it's not working, are you at least getting "value is not .txt file"?

Comment: yes, its showing "value is not .txt file". Btw, this is output with console of zipcodelist "["12345\r\n", "23456\r\n", "56789"]"

Comment: There's your problem. Why does it render `"12345\r\n"`. The values are not being found in the array because of the extra "\r\n\" that's getting appended to the number. Do you know what's causing that? Probably an issue with your .txt file? I'm guessing you have the txt file with your values on different lines. That's what is causing the /r/n.

Comment: You're right because if i already changed code to remove "/r/n" in array ouput this is working good. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your .txt file to look more like this:

`12345,23456,56789`

Don't add in line breaks like this:

`12345,
23456,
56789`

Comment: This wont work with my code at all (even with last variable in .txt file) @@

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I always find that when there seems to be no logical reason for why something won't work, it's because there's an issue with a variable somewhere